# broken micro SD slot and super glue on sd card

Tags: sd-card

After just a couple uses of my raspberry pi 3 B+, I saw that for some reason it wouldn't turn on. The problem, I found, was that slot for the micro SD card had fallen off. No matter how many time I tried to reattach it, it wouldn't stay. The easiest solution I thought was to use super glue, so I carefully applied some glue to the edges of the housing. It worked for a couple weeks until the slot fell off again. I thought that I must not have put enough super glue on, so I reapplied the glue making sure to use a bit more. This time however, when I put the SD card in, it still wouldn't turn on. When I took the SD card out to look at it, I saw that some super glue had dried on the gold filaments of the SD card. I don't know how to fix it and I really don't want to buy another raspberry pi. Soldering is not an available option for me right now. I could get a new SD card, but I want to make sure that I won't make the same mistake again. Does anyone have any advice that could help me?

Comment: peel off the super glue

Comment: Let me see.  Try something stronger than super glue, such as acetone stuff - Removing Super Glue
http://www.supergluecorp.com/?q=removingsuperglue.html  I also heard the rumour that you can boot from SD card connected to USB socket, instead of from SD card holder.  But I have not tried it, because my SD card holder is not yet broken! :)